# How to include a new menu in Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I need to include a new menu in the top at Kibana. I observed a query to remove a menu [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602467/can-i-change-top-menu-bar-and-remove-some-options-in-kibana-4)

But I want to add a menu.

All I did was

```
 var apps = require('registry/apps');
  apps.register(function TestAppModule() {
      return {
          id: 'test',
          name: 'TEST',
          order: 5
      };
  });
```

in kibana-4.1.2-windows\src\public\index.js

And I got  a menu, Now I want to redirect to a html, that I have designed, how should I be doing that.

Comment: I was able to add a sub menu, under "Settings", that was very doable, and was easy too, but placing a whole new Menu and submenu is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a matching controller for that, and connect the controller to the route.

Kibana's architecture relies on convention in some places, so since you gave your page the id `test` you need to create a controller named `test` as well.

For a good example look at the discover registration and controller (looking at kibana 4.1.2) :

The discover page is defined in `discover/index.js` as so (similar to what you did :

```
var apps = require('registry/apps');
  apps.register(function DiscoverAppModule() {
    return {
      id: 'discover',
      name: 'Discover',
      order: 0
    };
  });
```

And if you go to `plugins/discover/controllers/discover.js` you'll see the controller and it's definition.

In this file you will find the route definition which looks something like this :

```
require('routes')
  .when('/discover/:id?', {
    template: require('text!plugins/discover/index.html'),
    resolve: { ... }
  };
```

Notice that here the html file to display is configured for this route.

Then you need to "get" the app you defined already as so :
`var app = require('modules').get('apps/discover', [ ... ]);`

And then you can connect a controller to the app you defined, as so :
`app.controller('discover', function( ... ) { ... });`