# Hide search bar for particular dashboard in kibana

Tags: kibana-4

I am using kibana version 4.4.2 and I have nearly 7 dashboards in that kibana. I want to hide the search bar in one particular dashboard. Is it possible?

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602467/can-i-change-top-menu-bar-and-remove-some-options-in-kibana-4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602467/can-i-change-top-menu-bar-and-remove-some-options-in-kibana-4